# Only email on cron errors for jobs in cron.daily, cron.hourly, etc

Tags: linux, email, cron, crontab, cronjob

I have several cron jobs that run (in `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, etc.) and email `root@localhost` with the results. I'd like to stop those emails if the jobs are succeeding, and only email on error (which I understand can be done by redirecting `stdout` to `/dev/null`). I understand how to do that for individual cron jobs, but the scripts in those special directories are run using `run-parts`. What is the best way to suppress success emails for those scripts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to use one of the wrappers for the programs, that output everything when something goes bad and swallow stdout otherwise.

One example might be [cronic](http://habilis.net/cronic/), just prepend 'cronic' to 'run-parts' e.g.:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
 17 *  *   *   *  root  cd / && /etc/cronic run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

where `/etc/cronic` is a place with executable cronic script, downloaded from the website mentioned.

Comment: this works great.. `apt install cronic` and then put `chronic` in front of any command in crontab.. fyi, crontab -e file is located at `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` vs `/etc/crontab/`.. add `MAILTO=my@email.com` to it at the top.. it has 600 perms.

Answer (score 4):

You should send successful email notifications to `/dev/null` so they disappear.

But you want to see *unsuccessful* email notifications.

This means you need to first direct `stdout` to `/dev/null` and then direct `/dev/stderr` to `stdout`

try changing the redirection part of your cronjobs to

```
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

See [this link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/)

Comment: Wouldn't that suppress the error emails too (because they wouldn't produce any output)? Also, I need to do this for my `cron.XXX` directories which use `run-parts`, so it's not as simple as redirecting for individual scripts.

Comment: No the idea is that `stderr` is thrown away *then* `stderr` is redirected to `stdout`. I'm not sure what `run-parts` is, but however it works redirection of `stdout` and then `stderr` seems to be the way.

Comment: Aha, I googled `run-parts`. That does complicate the issue, doesn't it. Maybe you should avoid `run-parts` and invoke each script separately.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. `run-parts` runs all scripts in directories like `/etc/cron.daily`, so the trick is passing along the redirection to the individual scripts it is running.

Comment: I think so. I couldn't find anything about redirecting *all* output from `run-parts` (not even in the `man` page I just discovered I have.

Comment: Are you sure about the `>/dev/null 2>&1` bit? I tested it and that funnels everything to `/dev/null`, where if you drop the `2>&1` only stdout gets removed.

Comment: This is wrong. You are sending stderr to stdout which is being sent to /dev/null resulting in no output which means cron won't send an email.

Answer (score 1):

- If the script is well behaved, it will write only to `STDOUT` if
  successful, and to `STDERR` in case there is an error.
- By default, cron will mail everything that the script writes into
  `STDOUT` **or** `STDERR` ([Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cron#Handling_errors_of_jobs)).

So, if you want to keep error notifications, don't redirect `STDERR`, just `STDOUT`:

```
COMMAND > /dev/null
```

If you do the typical `>/dev/null 2>&1`, you are effectively suppressing both ([bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)).

1. Make `stdin` file descriptor a copy of /dev/null.
2. Make `stderr` file descriptor a copy of `stdout` (that already pointed to /dev/null).

Comment: Even if this does not fully answer the original question, it addresses some errors in [pavium's reply](https://superuser.com/a/290058/491366).